# How Does Google Maps Detect Compass Accuracy?

Tags: google-maps, compass

Modern versions of Google Maps display a cone of various widths for the compass, depending on how accurate/in need of calibration the compass is.

Given that the compass is simply a magnetometer and could be detecting either real magnetic fields external to the phone or calibration errors/magnetic fields coming from inside the phone, how does Google Maps know how accurate/well-calibrated the compass is at any given instant?

Comment: I've been in situations where a nearby strong magnetic field gave me incorrect compass direction. I'm not sure how accurate that "view cone" is on Google Maps beyond a general "the app believes that you are facing in _that_ direction"